# railflow cli command ignores the cucumber steps with data table. and only shows one line

Tags: testing, cucumber, testrail

we just started using testrail with railflow and I am using railflow cli command to create test cases that are written in cucumber/gherkin style. Test results are converted into json files and railflow cli reads those json files and create test cases in test rail. up to this point, everything works fine. However, recently realized that test scenarios where I use data table are not being transferred to my test case in test rail. Anyone had similar issue or suggesting any solution for this?

Here is cucumber step:
Then I verify "abc" table column headers to be
| columnName  |
| Subject     |
| Report Data |
| Action      |
| ER Type     |
in test rail, it only includes the header which is " Then I verify "abc" table column headers to be
"
any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

we are constantly improving Railflow and reports handling, so we are more than happy to add support for the cucumber data tables.

Please contact the support team via our [website](https://railflow.io)

Update: This is now implemented and available in [Railflow NPM CLI v. 2.1.12](https://www.npmjs.com/package/railflow)